# Reading a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives

[image: Photo of text]

> - The accountant made the writer to sign on the check.
> - They always make us laugh.

In these two sentences .. why is to sign used in first sentence instead of only SIGN? In second sentence why is only LAUGH used....Or can we use TO LAUGH?

Answer (score 1):

Modal verbs (except 'used to' and 'aught to'), verbs of perception like feel, hear, notice, observe, overhear, see, and watch and some causative verbs like 'let, make,and  bid' and certain comparative constructions ( had better, had sooner and ' but' in the sense 'except') , take bare infinitive (root verb forms without ' to'). In 'used to' and 'aught to'  the 'TO' particle is part of the verb, not of infinitives.

**In both the example sentences infinitives should be in bare forms.**

- The accountant made the writer sign on the cheque.
- They always make us laugh.